# Magento: Customising login failed message for customers?

Tags: php, magento

[image: Login failed]

I have a magento site where if the users email and password aren't valid, this message appears.

What I want is for the output of that message to reflect *which* credential was wrong. E.g 'wrong password' or 'wrong email address'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login action url is `http://domain.com/index.php/customer/account/loginPost/`

If you look into the Accountcontroller.php file  in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/` at `loginpostAction()`

Magento tries to load error message from **constant**,

```
switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                            $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
```

Here `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:` loads that message from 
 *Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php*

```
 public function authenticate($login, $password)
    {
        $this->loadByEmail($login);
        if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
            );
        }
        if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
            );
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
           'model'    => $this,
           'password' => $password,
        ));

        return true;
    }
```

Here you can see that message. But It's not a good idea to touch the core file. But you can achieve this by **rewriting** core modules.

Comment: How can I adapt this to check whether it's the email or the password that is incorrect?

Comment: Magento didn't care about whether it is wrong email or password. It just simply displays same message. Try to print the exception in your Accountcontroller.php,

`catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                 print_r($e->getCode()); exit;`
You will get `2` if email or password is wrong. Because that is declared in Customer.php file ,